# What's the purpose of the nachman song?

Tags: music, breslov

*Na nach nachma nachman meuman* is how the song goes. Is there a meaning behind the song other than than Nachman is from Uman? What is reason given for singing this song? Why do some feel such a strong need to publicize it?

Comment: Similar question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27249

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na Nach Breslovers (as opposed to all breslovers) chant this "song" based off a story that a letter fell from heaven, this letter was found by R Yisroel Ber Odesser. The letters contents said:

"It was very difficult for me to come down to you
my precious student to tell you that I had pleasure
very much from your devotion and upon you I said
my fire will burn until
Messiah is coming be strong and courageous
in your devotion
Na Nach Nachma Nachman Meuman
And with this I will reveal to you a secret and it is:
Full and heaped up from one extreme to another extreme 
And with the strengthening of your devotion you will understand it and a sign
The 17th of Tammuz they will say that you don't fast". (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na_Nach_Nachma_Nachman_Meuman)

Breslovers sing this with the belief that this "song" hastens the redemption. This song also aides meditation.

"[image: Fragment of a hand-written letter in Hebrew]

Comment: so they don't fast on the 17th of tammuz?

Comment: No. Just on that dsy r oddeser did not fast. He was feeling ill

Comment: ok that makes more sense. other than this letter which doesn't give much information other than the source and what singing this might accomplish are there any sources or anyone who discusses further why singing this has any connection to the geula?

Comment: @Mefaresh AFAIK he wasn't feeling ill, it was a bit more nuanced than that

Comment: http://nanach.org/ see this website if you can get past the slightly bad english